# Private keys & not buffer being passed to test file

Tags: solidity, truffle-test, hardhat

I'm running a test on a very simple pool contract. I am using Mocha to write the tests, but Hardhat's network to run them. After firing up my Hardhat node I get the 10 test accounts per usual with their test ETH, and I then try to reference a handful of those accounts in the test using Mocha's contract() function. However, my terminal reads the following when running the test itself:

`Error: This method only supports Buffer but input was: <private key>`

...where <private key> was the private key of my first test account I was looking to reference. Whenever I have this exact same testing setup when working with Truffle/Ganache exclusively this never came up, so I'm wondering if there is something breaking because I am using both Hardhat & Truffle concurrently; does Hardhat pass back a different value than Truffle does? I was always under the impression that the conversion from the private key to the buffer happened under the hood when using Truffle/Hardhat. Is there an explanation and a workaround for this?

For reference, here is my test file as well:

```
const { assert } = require('chai');
const Pool = artifacts.require('Pool.sol');

contract('Pool', ([accounts]) => {
    const [admin, user1, user2, user3, _] = accounts;

    it('should accept deposits and read correct balances for contract and users', async () => {
        const pool = await Pool.new('Pool', true);

        await pool.makeDeposit({
            from: user1,
            value: web3.utils.toWei('1'),
        });

        await pool.makeDeposit({
            from: user2,
            value: web3.utils.toWei('1'),
        });

        await pool.makeDeposit({
            from: user3,
            value: web3.utils.toWei('2'),
        });

        await pool.getPoolBalance();
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are running into this issue: https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/1885

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the same error after upgrading `@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5` to version `^2.0.1`.  I believe there is a breaking change in that release.

Revert to version 2.0.0 using this command, and this error will go away.

```bash
npm install "@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5"@"2.0.0
```

Comment: You can also upgrade to 2.0.2, which fixes this problem.